# Skip celery warnings

Tags: django, celery, bamboo

I have build plan for Bamboo Atlassian. For one of my task I should start celery, but Bamboo thinks that it has critical errors and makes builds failed:

```
[WARNING/MainProcess] /home/web/.virtualenvs/project-web/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/loaders.py:132: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments! warnings.warn("Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never "
[WARNING/MainProcess] celery@bamboo ready.
```

I can't run project with settings.DEBUG=False.
How can I skip such errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a celery settings with which you can specify the log level of things written to stdout within celery processes. It's `CELERY_REDIRECT_STDOUTS_LEVEL`. Use e.g. in your configuration:

```
CELERY_REDIRECT_STDOUTS_LEVEL = 'INFO'
```

Take a look at the docs:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/2.2/configuration.html

I'm not sure about the second log line, but the first should go away.